# How to filter views results based on entity reference field

Tags: 7, entities, views

I use Drupal 7 and [entityreference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference) module. 
I have a content type with a entity refenrece field to users called field_users_referenced.

So I created a view with views module and list nodes of thats content type.
I want to order this views result based on field_users_referenced.

when I add field_users_referenced field on filter fields, and set it for exposed filter , after type a field_users_referenced value on thats field, have no any result.

I **do not want** to filter field_users_referenced with select box, I want to type value on exposed filter field and order results.

please help me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Advance View Settings -> Add Relationship -> Select Entity Reference Field

Then in filters -> add Filter-> Select field from the respective entity.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In Drupal 8, you can do one of the following.  These are in order from more recommended to less recommended:

1. Apply the latest core patch from [Generalize TaxonomyIndexTid filter to be available for all entity reference fields](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2429699) (unless it's been committed by the time you're reading this),
2. Use the [Entity Reference Exposed Filters](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_reference_exposed_filters) module, or
3. Follow the instructions in [Entity reference filter with Drupal 8](https://antistatique.net/en/we/blog/2015/10/06/entity-reference-filter-with-drupal-8), which require custom code.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add your entity reference field as a relation to the view, and then you can use the fields from the User entity type in you filter section and configure it/them as you please.

Answer (score 1):

Based on of the @Colan solution. Add the following Patch to your `composer.json` file

```
"extra": {
    "patches": {
        "drupal/core": {
            "View Entity Reference Field" : "https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2019-12-24/drupal-generalize-taxonomyindextid-filter-2429699-277.patch"
        }
    }
}
```

then run `composer install` and **Rebuild the cache**.

Comment: This answer assumes that the same patch should always be used, which I don't recommend.  As per my answer, you should use the most recent good patch listed in the issue.  If would be nice if you were to edit my answer to include this as a template, making it clear what should be changed depending on the patch (instead of posting this answer).

Answer (score 1):

There is another way for Drupal8. Try using the [verf](https://www.drupal.org/project/verf) module